# How I can display MySQL data in my canvas tag?

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, canvas, html5-canvas

In the canvas I am unable to display html elements directly in the canvas tag, I need to display data from my database in this canvas and I was wondering if my method looks good and secure enough to display them and I kinda doubt it honestly.

Since a request from my express router I retrieve the data from my database with a function and I send it in an object **( nana: result[0].name )** *in my hbs page.*

```
exports.ioo = function (req, res) {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?', ["Fada"], (error, result) => {
    console.log(result[0].name);
    res.render("test", {
      nana: result[0].name
    });
  })
}
```

*Then I get the object sent in a handlebars tag from my game.hbs page on the client side.* **{{ nana }}**

```
<canvas id="game" height="400" width="400">
        <p id="ppp">{{nana}}</p>
        <p>test</p>
</canvas>
```

*Then, in my game.js which contains the logic of the game I get the element* **{{nana}}**
*and its value to display it directly in my canvas with* **the method fillText(nanaElement, 50, 50)**

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const nanaElement = document.getElementById("ppp").textContent;

console.log(a)

ctx.fillText(nanaElement, 50, 50);
```

**I use node.js and mysql.**

**Thank you for your answers !**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works just fine. You most likely have a problem of the DOM not being ready when your code starts, and therefor nothing is loaded or written to the canvas. Double check your console for errors, or check for race conditions.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const nanaElement = document.getElementById("ppp").textContent;

ctx.fillText(nanaElement, 50, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="game" height="400" width="400">
        <p id="ppp">{{nana}}</p>
        <p>test</p>
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer i gonna check that